# confusing/critical Bug in git remote push command( DELETED BRANCH INSTEAD OF UPDATING IT)

Tags: git, github

While working with the git remote push command faced a **dangerous bug**

command to push code from one local/remote to another remote branch

```
git push <remote> <local branch name>:<remote branch to push into>
```

**But if you mention space in after local/remote source branch  name before colon (:) it will delete the target remote branch**

```
git push <remote> <local branch name>(single space):<remote branch to push into>
```

For me

```
git push origin dev_test:develop(Pushed changes to remote develop)
```

And

```
git push origin dev_test :develop(deleted remote develop)
```

**Note:** dev_test had new changes and was feature branch of develop

**Feel free to dislike this question you highly reputed peoples who doesn't even understand my question But as per coding standard
IF the command doesn't has --delete or -d in it , it shouldn't delete the repo**

Comment: Correct, that's the syntax to delete a local branch.

Comment: @EdwardThomson delete a local branch? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  That's the syntax to delete a *remote* branch.

Comment: @edward ... Really can you show me that syntax in the official doc

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question. It's a bug report.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: More precisely, it's an attempt to claim that what is a documented feature, is a bug. (Admittedly something that is a documented feature could very well *be* a bug :-) )

Comment: @abhinavkumar [Here is the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203): "*Pushing an **empty <src>** allows you to **delete the <dst>** ref from the remote repository.*" Emphasize mine — *phd*.

Comment: @torek: I never said it's a *good* or even a *valid* bug report ;-)

Comment: Next time please raise a question of a "bug" you'll discover in SQL for the `DELETE` statement without a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Next time I will sure not to raise any issue or bug..... Because as per the Great peoples involved.... Any thing mentioned directly or indirectly in the doc whether it makes sence or not are correct

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, this is a documented feature.

> Pushing an empty `<src>` allows you to delete the `<dst>` ref from the remote repository.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: Can you show where it is mentioned in the documents that if I put space it will delete the remote repo and if I don't mention space it will push the code???

Comment: I didn't mention pushing empty source in the command

Comment: People sometime can't identify that one space has be mentioned while working on the terminal... One space in the command and your remote repo deleted.... That is considered as bug

Comment: @abhinavkumar: in shells, white-space separates arguments, so `git push origin this :that` means that you want to run the `git` command with four separate arguments: `push`, `origin`, `this`, and `:that`. The documentation clearly specifies that `:that` is a request to delete branch `that`. Note that in your case you merely need to run `git push origin this:that` (no spaces around the colon) to fix the situation.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense ..adding single space deleting the repository and without any space pushing changes to repository....A command should atleast make sense